# Php script to upload photos for single user and protect them

Tags: php, upload, access-control

I need to build a php script to upload images in a folder, store the name of the image on the database (Mysql in my case), protect the folder from direct access (probably using .htaccess) and get the images only if the user insert them in his post.

But how to do that? I'm not an expert in this type of thing and i don't know how to do this.

How to protect images from direct access? This is my primary problem.

Please, someone know were can I find a good guide for this? Or can someone teach me how can I do that?

Comment: Thank you Lajos for the information. Unfortunately I did not find this guide first. Thank you, I'm sorry :-)

Comment: No problem, Leo, the important thing is that your question has a nicely described answer.